# Linq Query C# returning 1st value only

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to retrieve a selected record from the database, but always getting the 1st record returned

Here is my query:

```
ClientSMSAccount smsAccount = rad.ClientSMSAccounts
                                          .Where(x => (x.CompanyID == companyId) && (x.CountryID == ClientSMSAccountModal.CountryID))
                                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

ClientSMSAccountModal.CountryID = 2, but it's returning the 1st record from the DB

Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly here?

**Edit:**

Each record is distinguished by CompanyID and CountryID. 
There are many CompanyID's for each CounrtyID.

So If I query the data by CompanyID and CountryID, it should return the exact record only. However it's returning the 1st record from the database :(

**Database Values:**

```
CompanyID = 1 - CountryID = 1
CompanyID = 1 - CountryID = 2
```

Comment: What are the values in the first row of the database?

Comment: Look at the CompanyID and the CountryID returned from the query as `smsAccount `. Do they match the values you specified in your Where clause?

Comment: I've added the database values now.

Comment: I only want the 2nd row of values returned

Comment: I think you're somehow mistaking the correct return, this is simple enough query that if you provide correct ids, you'll get correct data

Comment: @AD.Net  When I pass in CompanyID = 1 and CountryID = 2, it returns the 1st row instead of the 2md. Not sure why?

Comment: Are you sure `ClientSMSAccountModal.CountryID` has 2 as value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are selecting first or the default value (which is null here) and assign to a single object, if you need the whole values means you have to use like this:

```
List<ClientSMSAccount> smsAccounts = rad.ClientSMSAccounts
                                        .Where(x => (x.CompanyID == companyId) && (x.CountryID == ClientSMSAccountModal.CountryID))
                                        .ToList();
```

If you are looking for the last value means you can try with LastOrDefault like the following:

```
ClientSMSAccount smsAccount = rad.ClientSMSAccounts
                                  .LastOrDefault(x => (x.CompanyID == companyId) && (x.CountryID == ClientSMSAccountModal.CountryID))
```

Comment: This will give me a list, I only want the 2nd record from my sample data above

Comment: @Orion: I have updated the answer please have a look

Comment: I need the exact record. If I use LastOrDefault, then I'll end up with the same problem when trying to retrieve the 1st record

Comment: How do you identity the second row

Comment: Check my sample data. 2nd row has CompanyID = 1, CountryID = 2

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ClientSMSAccount> smsAccount = rad.ClientSMSAccounts
                                      .Where(x => (x.CompanyID == companyId) && (x.CountryID == ClientSMSAccountModal.CountryID))
                                      .ToList();
```

is what you have to do.
Catch: List and .ToList()

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. Although it could be simplified to:

```
clientSMSAccount smsAccount = rad.ClientSMSAccounts
                             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompanyID == companyId && x.CountryID == ClientSMSAccountModal.CountryID);
```

I imagine that the problem is that either `companyId` or `ClientSMSAccountModal.CountryID` does not contain the value you think. Maybe try hard coding them to start with to see what you get.

Comment: The values are correct. I've written them to a text file to make sure they are being passed correctly from the view.

Comment: Even when I hard code the CounrtyID to 2, it still pulls the 1st record from the database only :(

Comment: Very odd. I'd try instantiating the whole collection (`List<ClientSMSAccount> smsAccount = rad.ClientSMSAccounts.ToList();`) to see what is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment in another answer that you want the *second* record, you need to use `Skip(1)` before you call `FirstOrDefault()`(Assuming you can guarantee that there is at least 1 record)

```
ClientSMSAccounts
.Where(x => (x.CompanyID == companyId) && (x.CountryID == ClientSMSAccountModal.CountryID))
.Skip(1)
.FirstOrDefault();
```